# Need xpath for selecting checkbox in selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is the html code... I want to know which xpath can I use to select such a check box.

In actual HTML code I have multiple `td` for checkboxes, here I have shown only one.

I already tried

```
driver.findElement(By.id("cntMain_GridView1_chIndividual_0")).click();
```

but it gives an error saying no such element found on web page.

```
<table id="cntMain_GridView1" class="table iconTwo" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="no-sorting" valign="top" align="left" style="width:10px;">
        <p class="defaultP" tabindex="35">
          <span style="display:inline-block;width:5%;">
            <div class="ez-checkbox">
              <div class="ez-checkbox">
                <input id="cntMain_GridView1_chIndividual_0" class="ez-hide" type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:RbtnOnOff(this.id);" name="ctl00$cntMain$GridView1$ctl02$chIndividual" tabindex="-1"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </span>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is the checkbox within a `frame`?

Comment: No, there is no frame or window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `display` style property of the element and then clicking on the element. Use `JavascriptExecutor` to make the element visible. Try the following code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String domain_name = (String) js.executeScript("return document.getElementById(" +
             "'cntMain_GridView1_chIndividual_0').style.visibility = 'visible'");

driver.findElement(By.id("cntMain_GridView1_chIndividual_0")).click();
```